# Calling a function/making 'div' container visible on change of value in dropdown box using knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a dropdown box with 4 options.

Then, I have 4 div containers which I have made invisible using `style="display:none"`.

I want that on selection for each particular option ,div container corresponding to that option be made visible and rest div containers remain invisible using KnockoutJs.

e.g
array is:

```
this.Types=ko.observableArray([{name:'op1'},{name:'op2'},{name:'op3'},{name:'op4'}]);
```

html:

```
<select data-bind='options:Types, optionsCaption:"(Select a Type)", optionsText:"name", value:seltype'></select>  

<div> id=1 style="display:none"> id1 </div>     
<div id=2 style="display:none"> id2 </div>  
<div id=3 style="display:none"> id3 </div>  
<div id=4 style="display:none"> id4 </div>
```

Comment: It's `visibility: hidden;` or `display: none;`. Choose one.

Comment: <select data-bind='options:Types, optionsCaption:"(Select a Type)", optionsText:"name", value:seltype'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using the *visible* binding on the DIVs elements:

```
<select data-bind='options:Types, optionsCaption:"(Select a Type)", optionsText:"name", optionsValue: "name", value:seltype'></select>  

<div data-bind="visible: seltype() === 'op1'"> id1 </div>     
<div data-bind="visible: seltype() === 'op2'"> id2 </div>  
<div data-bind="visible: seltype() === 'op3'"> id3 </div>  
<div data-bind="visible: seltype() === 'op4'"> id4 </div>
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7K4d/) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the selected value of the dropdown as follows:

```
<select data-bind='options:Types, optionsCaption:"(Select a Type)", optionsText:"name", value:seltype'></select>  
<div id="div1" style="display:none"> id1 </div>     
<div id="div2" style="display:none"> id2 </div>  
<div id="div3" style="display:none"> id3 </div>  
<div id="div4" style="display:none"> id4 </div>  

this.seltype = ko.observable();   
this.Types=ko.observableArray([{id:1, name:'op1'},{id:2,name:'op2'},{id:3,name:'op3'},{id:4,name:'op4'}]);

this.seltype.subscribe(function(newValue){
    // jquery
    $.("#div1,#div2,#div3,#div4").hide();
    $.("#div" + newValue).show();
});
```